# Override mule poll

Tags: database, mule, quartz-scheduler, esb, polling

I would like to override Mule's poll frequency, to be exponential. My requirement is to poll a database say every 5sec, but if the results do not match expected value, I want to increase the polling interval exponentially to say 20 sec, 60 sec, 5min etc and once there is a match I want to switch back to original polling interval of 5sec.Repeat this process from there on. I do not see such options from the core component.Is this possible to achieve in mule.

```
 <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="1000"/>
            <db:select config-ref="myDbConnector" doc:name="Database">
             <db:parameterized-query> select value from xyz;</db:parameterized-query>
            </db:select>
  </poll>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by if results do not match expected value ?? What value are you expecting ??

Comment: I am polling the database for a specific result. If I do not get expected results, I will poll it again. For your detail,say there is another process in my application, which will update this 'value' to  say 'done'. Now my requirement is to keep looking for this 'done', once I see this match, I will kick off the next process. Hope that helps you understand. But I think its is irrelevant to concern about what the select statement should do. As said, my main aim is to be able to override the way database polling is done. I want to change the fixed frequency to exponential frequency.

Comment: Could not find a way so far...quartz also does not appear to solve the issue.. I do read about AbstractPollingMessageReceiver, but not quite sure if that would be right fit and how do I extend  it